# nullreference exception unhandled in selectionChanged event

Tags: c#, xaml

I have two text boxes named `txtChange` and `txtStatus`. `XAML` code is as follows.

```
<TextBox Height="29" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="418,385,0,0" Name="txtChange" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="264" Text="Make a selection in this textbox" SelectionChanged="txtChange_SelectionChanged" />
<TextBox Height="87" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="418,438,0,0" Name="txtStatus" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="264" Text="Initialized text" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Now I have a selectionChanged event for one textbox defined as:

```
private void txtChange_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt2 = sender as TextBox;
    txtStatus.Text = "Selection is " + txt2.SelectedText + "";
}
```

[image]

Could someone please explain what is going on? I have only the `InitializeComponent();` in the MainWindow Constructor.

---

Edit: the issue gets resolved when I did not initialize Text in XAML. Any idea why?

Comment: Not sure, but I've had issues using `Name`. Try using `x:Name`.

Comment: debug your code and see what is the type of _sender_

Comment: @Selman22 sender is {System.Windows.Controls.TextBox: Make a selection in this textbox}

Comment: @JohnnyMopp tried using x:Name. still the same.

Comment: @Tomtom no. It was not null. the issue gets resolved by removing Text attributes from XAML code. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `event SelectionChanged` which is raised in initialization. When `TextBox` txtChange is initialized and `Text` property is assigned the event raised and we get null reference exception in `txtStatus` because it is still uninitialized. The `InitializeComponent();` initializes your UI, you can find in Obj\Debug|Release folder files MainWindow.g.cs and MainWindow.i.cs files which contains the autogenerated code of `InitializeComponent();`.

Comment: Could you please explain why is that? And using this doesn't solve the issue. I think the problem might be in 'txtStatus'

Comment: Where is Textoxes declared? Is there in template?

Comment: MainWindow.xaml And MainWindow.cs are the files we are talking about here. I am learning XAML and faced this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the second TextBox to show the text of the first, use the following XAML

```
<TextBlock Height="87" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="418,438,0,0" Name="txtStatus" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="264" Text="{Binding SelectedText, ElementName=txtChange}"/>
```

Notice that I changed your `TextBox` to a `TextBlock` and I am binding the Text to the SelectedText of the Textbox